What spell attacks are NOT affected by Innate Sorcery?
In the 2024 PHB, sorcerers get Innate Sorcery. The text for it reads:

[for the next minute] You have Advantage on the attack rolls of Sorcerer spells you cast.

I'm interested in the restrictions of "Sorcerer spells". If a multiclassed Sorcerer activates Innate Sorcery, what spell attacks (cast in the next minute) would not benefit from Advantage?
Please note there are a few scenarios to consider:

A spell that is only available via multiclassing but cast using shared spell slots. For example, a cleric/sorcerer casting Guiding Bolt or a warlock/sorcerer using Eldritch Blast.
A spell learned via the multiclass, cast using a shared spell slot, but available on the Sorcerer spell list. For example, a warlock/sorcerer that learned Firebolt as a level one warlock.
A spell learned as a sorcerer but cast by a warlock/sorcerer using a Warlock pact slot.
Spells gained through Feats such as Magic Initiate or Fey Touched.

[Edited to add] Based on What makes a spell being cast considered to be a {class} spell?, the answers seem to be:

Yes, if it's on the sorcerer spell list and learned as a sorcerer.
No, if it's not on the sorcerer spell list.
No, if it's on both the sorcerer spell list and multiclass spell list but you learn the spell via the multiclass.
Yes, if it's learned from a feat that specifies it's a sorcerer spell (e.g. Magic Initiate).


Innate Sorcery applies to any spell you cast that is on the Sorcerer Spell List or specified as a sorcerer spell for you.
RAW Innate Sorcery does not stipulate "your sorcerer spells", so it applies to all Sorcerer spells; even spells learned through a different class; even unlearned spells (e.g. when it is cast through a spell scroll, magic item, or event), even when gained through a feat, and even when cast through Pact Magic/Warlock slots.

you can use the spell slots you gain from Pact Magic to cast spells you have prepared from classes with the Spellcasting feature...

While it is the case that

You determine what spells you can prepare for each class individually...

and

Each spell you prepare is associated with one of your classes, and you use the spellcasting ability of that class when you cast the spell.

Innate Sorcery, as written, ignores those nuances.
Additionally, some features might specify that a spell, which does not appear on the Sorcerer Class Spell List is "nevertheless a sorcerer spell for you".
As long as you cast the spell, it's on the Sorcerer Class Spell List, or some rules specify that it's a Sorcerer Spell for you, Innate Sorcerer applies. Therefore, the answer to your question is the set of spells to which those conditions do not apply:

Where T is the universal set of all spells.
